# link_to_remote not defined in vanilla Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype, link-to-remote

I'm getting into Ajax, obviously using Prototype, and just getting to the point of switching from `link_to` to `link_to_remote` (because I want to make a background request of the server). The problem? The server claims that `link_to_remote` is not defined. I keep reading that all you need to do is make sure that prototype is defined thus:

`<%= javascript_include_tag "prototype" %>` (I've included it in the `application.html.erb` file)

I still had link_to_remote undefined, and anyway I couldn't figure out how including javascript would define helper code, so I added actionpack to my Gemfile. It successfully installed, I have a good path for it, I rebooted rails server, and `link_to_remote` is STILL undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Rails 3.0.x running into this issue.

`link_to_remote` is deprecated in favor of `link_to 'Foobar', foobar_path, :remote => true`.

You probably want to jump on the jQuery bandwagon. Rails 3.1 ships with jQuery by default, and I'm sure future versions will too (for a while at least).

Comment: Thank you very much, Corey. That's exactly what I needed. Funny how hard it is to acquire such simple information...